# Open Graph meta tags not parsing

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to generate custom og:meta tags to enable us to publish actions through the Open Graph API, the tags appear to be rendering fine in the page, but do not get picked up by the linter.

The staging url you can see here: http://yamgo.tv/zing, and you will see the following meta tags in the head block:

```
<meta name="fb:app_id" content="361493867250674">
<meta name="og:type" content="yamgo-tv-test:channel">
<meta name="og:url" content="http://desktop.dev/zing">
<meta name="og:title" content="Zing">
<meta name="og:image" content="http://yamgo.mobi/images/xxhigh/logo/ZingLogo.jpg">
```

However, if I use the URL linter for Facebook, I get the following:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fyamgo.tv%2Fzing

The linter is telling me that I don't have a og:type tag (which I do), and that I have other missing tags such as `og:title` which I also have.

This is only a staging site; does this affect the correct linting of the tags? I thought it would lint correctly even if the site wasn't fully live.

Thanks

G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of your OG meta tags is wrong.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

Comment: *Facepalm* Thanks, I'd looked at that for hours as well :D